# How to parse a Json coming back as Bytes Literal in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-requests

I am making a simple call to an API and getting what appears to me as a bytes array as Json returning from the call. When I try to get a field from the Json object I get the following error message: TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

I am using the requests package:

```
    response = requests.post(myUrl, 
                         json=myJson, headers=myHeaders) 
    foo = response.content
```

foo is a Json object:

```
  {"aaa":    
      {
         "bbb":"bbb content",
         "ccc":"ccc content"    
      } 
  }
```

calling foo['aaa'] results in the following error: error message: TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str.

How do I fix this?

Comment: `foo` is a `bytes` object, which happens to be in JSON format. The solution is to *deserialize the JSON*. Luckily, requests has a handy helper method, use `foo = response.json()` which is equivalent to `import json; foo = json.loads(response.content.decode())`

Comment: Thanks! That solves it. If you would like to copy and paste this as the answer, I will mark it as the answer.